# What is unavailable memory in assembler?(TASM)

Tags: assembly

As I read in book, by address [2] we can find address of first byte of unavailable memory.
I try to write something and then read it. If I didn't make a mistake, I did this operations. So what is unavailable memory in assembler?

```
CODE SEGMENT                  
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:CODE, ES:NOTHING

org 256     
;------start-------
STARTPROC       PROC

        mov di, 2
        ;in ax is adress of unavailible byte                    
        mov ax, [di]                                
        ;now es point on unavailable memory
        mov es, ax
        mov bx, 0FFFFh
        ;write with offset=2
        mov es:[di], bx

        ;read es:[di]
        mov ax, es:[di]
        mov di, offset temp
        add di, 3
        call WRD_TO_HEX
        mov dx, offset temp

        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h

        ret
STARTPROC       ENDP    

temp        db 4    DUP ('0'), '$'

TETR_TO_HEX     PROC near
        and AL, 0Fh
        cmp AL, 09
        jbe NEXT
        add AL, 07
   NEXT:add AL, 30h
        ret
TETR_TO_HEX     ENDP

BYTE_TO_HEX     PROC near
        push CX
        mov AH, AL
        call TETR_TO_HEX
        xchg AL,AH
        mov CL, 4
        shr AL, CL
        call TETR_TO_HEX
        pop CX
        ret
BYTE_TO_HEX     ENDP

WRD_TO_HEX      PROC near
        push BX
        mov BH, AH
        call BYTE_TO_HEX
        mov [DI], AH
        dec DI
        mov [DI], AL
        dec DI
        mov AL, BH
        call BYTE_TO_HEX
        mov [DI], AH
        dec DI
        mov [DI], AL
        pop BX
        ret
WRD_TO_HEX      ENDP

CODE ENDS
        end STARTPROC
```

Proc TETR_TO_HEX, BYTE_TO_HEX, WRD_TO_HEX is needed to parse information.

I write FFFF to unavailable memory with offset=2, then read it right. What is wrong?

Comment: "Unavailable memory" might mean that you are not *allowed* to use it because it is already in use by someone else, perhaps the operating system.

Comment: If you're not doing any OS-related thing, you should get rid of the ancient TASM or any 16-bit DOS assembler ASAP. The DOS era has gone decades ago

Answer (score 0):

The second instruction

```
     mov ax, [di]
```

seems to assume that ds points to segment 0. The address you want is probably on absolute address (realmode), so 0000:0002, so make sure you save a segment register, load it with 0, and use that in the above instruction.

Before you change a segment register, push it on the stack first, and pop it back later. (before you return or call another procedure or the system)

Comment: If I recall correctly (possibly not!), PSP:0002 (not 0000:0002) holds last paragraph allocated, not first unavailable paragraph. As Bo points out, this probably means that dos is using it, not that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @FrankKotler My book say that it is adress of first unavailable byte.